# How to avoid security dialog when accessing AppointmentItem Body in Outlook 2003 custom addin

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-2003

I have created an Outlook 2003 addin in VSTO 2005.  I am trying access appointment Item's body.  When this statement runs, Outlook pops up a security dialog where it ask for whether to allow to access the information or not.  How can we bypass this check or any additional setting we need to do so it will not appear?

Comment: I assume C#? Can you post the part of your code that instantiates the Outlook.Application object?

Comment: I don't instantiate a new object.  I access from current Addin's property this.Application.ActiveExploerer().Selection[1].

Comment: What does 'this' refer to? I am not familiar with C#, but I know that Outlook addins will not trigger the security prompt if they use the native Outlook.Application object.

Comment: this code is written into ThisAddIn class, which is a starting point for a addin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the inbuilt security feature.  If we tries to access body of the Appointment, it will throw security dialog.  It can't be avoided, until AddIn dll made trusted.